# How do I show a channel in dm in DISCORD.JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

[image]

All I can find is how to send a message to a specific channel, I want to send a specific channel in a dm with my bot.
`I am trying to send a channel in dm in discord.js for a minigame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the `Channel` object and it'll work.

```js
const Channel = client.channels.cache.get("ChannelID");
message.author.send(`Hello, please check the channel ${Channel}. Thank you.`);
```

---

You can also do that as a normal user. You need to write: `<#ChannelID>`